# OnDelete Function does not work in react Task Tracker

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently learning react by watching a tutorial on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7ejDZ8SWv8&t=762s).Around the 51:40 mark where we focus on delete task and prop drilling, OnDelete function seems to not work at all. After adding OnDelete is the files where I was indicated nothing happened. Not sure what could be causing the issue.

App.js

```
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Tasks from "./components/Tasks";
import { useState } from "react";
function App() {
  const [tasks, setTask] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "Doctors Appointment",
      day: "February 5th at 2:30pm",
      reminder: true,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "Meeting at School",
      day: "February 6th at 1:30pm",
      reminder: true,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      text: "Food shopping",
      day: "February 5th at 2:30pm",
      reminder: false,
    },
  ]);

  //Delete Task List
  const deleteTask = () => {
    console.log("delete");
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Header title="Task Tracker" />
      <Tasks tasks={tasks} onDelete={deleteTask} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Task.js

```
import { FaTimes } from "react-icons/fa";

const Task = ({ task, OnDelete }) => {
  return (
    <div className="task">
      <h3>
        {task.text}{" "}
        <FaTimes
          styles={{ color: "red", cursor: "pointer" }}
          onClick={OnDelete}
        />{" "}
      </h3>

      <p>{task.day}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Task;
```

Tasks.js

```
import Task from "./Task";
const Tasks = ({ tasks, onDelete }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {tasks.map((task) => (
        <Task key={task.id} task={task} onDelete={onDelete} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default Tasks;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are destructuring `onDelete`  incorrectly in `Task.js`.It should be `onDelete` instead of `OnDelete`. Updated component:

```
import { FaTimes } from "react-icons/fa";

const Task = ({ task, onDelete }) => {
  return (
    <div className="task">
      <h3>
        {task.text}{" "}
        <FaTimes
          styles={{ color: "red", cursor: "pointer" }}
          onClick={OnDelete}
        />{" "}
      </h3>

      <p>{task.day}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Task;
```

Comment: Thank you so much . Can't believe I made such a small error.